# EF generate two FK by one relationship

Tags: entity-framework-6

EF 6.1.3

Mapping

```
        var b = mb.Entity<PAYMENT_INVOICE>();
        b.ToTable("T_PAYMENT_INVOICE");
        b.HasPrimaryKey(x => x.Id);
        b.Property(x => x.OrdersSumm).IsRequired();
        b.Property(x => x.MargaSumm).IsRequired();
        b.Property(x => x.DeliverySumm).IsRequired();
        b.Property(x => x.PaySumm).IsRequired();
        b.Property(x => x.CreateDate).IsRequired();
        b.Property(x => x.Sended).IsRequired();
        b.Property(x => x.LastError).IsOptional();

        b.HasOptional(x => x.Payment).WithMany(x => x.Invoices).HasForeignKey(x => x.PaymentId);
        b.HasRequired(x => x.Client).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ClientId);
        b.HasRequired(x => x.Purchase).WithMany(x => x.Invoices).HasForeignKey(x => x.PurchaseId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Why generate this key and column? Both are equal.

[image]

I remove column `PURCHASE_ID` and `FK_dbo.T_PAYMENT_INVOICE_dbo.T_PURCHASE_PURCHASE_Id`.

When I save `PAYMENT_INVOICE` I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'PURCHASE_Id'

I do not need a second key, what is my mistake?

Comment: The `Purchase_Id` is the **column** holding the FK value, while `FK_dbo.T_PAYMENT_INVOICE_dbo.T_PURCHASE_PURCHASE_Id` is the **constraint** (the "rule", if you will) that defines that there is a foreign key relationship between those tables. Those are **two separate things** - and you need **BOTH** to have a proper FK relationship

Comment: I have two equal columns: PurchaseId (named by my mapping) and PURCHASE_Id (named by EF), and I have two equal keys.

Comment: The Purchase_Id is (usually) auto generated by EF. Are you using code first or model first? I also see one if nullable so what does it look like in the model?

Comment: I use code first. Other relationships (Client, Payment) generated by mapping correctly. Problem with Purchase. Client is the same relationship as Purchase, mappings are also the same. Why EF generate FK by Client correctly, but by Purchase generate wrong (two colums and two FK)?

Comment: Is there a difference in the cascade rules for the generated keys? Also, I noticed that `PurchaseId` is not nullable and `PURCHASE_Id` is nullable. Do you have automatic migrations on? Are you writing your own? Was `Purchase` an optional relationship in the past?